# Part-time yeshiva in london

Tags: yeshiva-school

Does anyone know if there is a yeshiva in **London** allowing you to go to university at the same time?

Comment: I thought the Montefiore semicha program was a part-time one allowing for college, but I could certainly be mistaken.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to try Brampton Bet Midrash: https://www.wearechazak.com/locations/london

Comment: This is not a "yeshiva" - it is a beis hamedrash that has set masechta they are working through. If this is what the OP wants there are loads of these options here in London.

Comment: @Dov sorry. I asked a Rabbi from London and this is what he suggested, but you know better than me if you live there!

Comment: Dov, (and OP) BBM has a full morning seder and night seder program (afternoon seder normally left for university.) With 3 minyanim a day, Shiurim in Halacha, Parsha, Hashkafa, Mussar, Thursday night Mishmar etc. There are not loads of these options. This is the only "full" day option for someone that wants to do University and learn.